# Django admin 'is a' relationships

Tags: django, django-admin

I've had plenty of experience in Django but I'm very new to the admin app (we usually build everything into the page as per project requirements).

But now I'm working on a project that requires some admin work and I'm stuck on one part.

Say I have Database models - Person, Student, Faculty

Both Faculty and Student 'is a' Person (they inherit those attributes so to speak).  How can I show this in the admin view?

So that when someone clicks to add a student they fill out the student only attributes, but also the attributes required the Person model on the same page.  Is this possible?

Here's the models, there's also Faculty but it's similar to Student

```
class Person(models.Model):
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mi = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    cell = models.CharField(max_length=20)



class Student(models.Model):
    year = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    stud_id = models.IntegerField()
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    #many to many
```

Any ideas or further questions would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[InlineModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) is your answer! 
 check it out!

Here is the code you need:

```
class StudentInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Student

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        StudentInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(Person,PersonAdmin)
```

Comment: Well I tried it and I'm getting an error:

<class 'school.models.Person'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'school.models.Student'>

Comment: Sorry. My mistake! I made in a oposite way! try it now!

Comment: Great that appears to be what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use Django model inheritance like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mi = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    cell = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Student(Person):
    year = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    stud_id = models.IntegerField()
```

This way, in the Student Admin page, you will get all the fields from `Student` AND from `Person` without `Inlines`. Also Django will deal automatically with the ForeignKey between the 2 tables.

[Docs on Model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance).